# How to fix Laravel BadMethodCallException when using Entrust

Tags: php, laravel, entrust

Always getting the

```
  [BadMethodCallException]
  This cache store does not support tagging.
```

when ever i try to run a database command that include the save function it produce this error and i think is because of the Entrust.

On the RegisterController it displays the same error of

```
  [BadMethodCallException]
  This cache store does not support tagging.
```

but it still registers the user. all the same but any other part of the code is halt. How do i fix this error.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

register controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Correct this I went entirely out of Entrust Package and Create a fresh

> ROLE PERMISSION MODEL AND TABLE WITH THE SAME SCHEMA

as entrust run the database migration with and use tinker to fill the datas.

> NEXT I EDITED THE MIDDLEWARE OF ENTRUST TO SEE MY ROLE, PERMISSION AS
>   STRINGS

after you create your model. Just to `Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole` and just remove the explode function. to this for the other two middlewares

Answer (score 0):

Set `CACHE_DRIVER=array` in your `.env` file.

[Source](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/issues/468#issuecomment-169216618)

Comment: it does n't work. i have to create my ROLE AND PERMISSION MODEL and ATTACH IT TO ENTRUST PACKAGE IT WORKS FINE FOR ME NOW